# What is the equivalent of a Win32 message pump in Linux?

Tags: c++, linux

In Windows, to pump for system messages (for a game, for example) one would roughly do this:

```
MSG msg;
while (PeekMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
{
   TranslateMessage(&msg);
   DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

I've never done development on Linux (I'm on Mint v17 at the moment) before, so I'm not sure what the equivalent (if any) would be. I did some self-research on this but didn't find much help, most likely because I am unaware of the proper linux terminology for such concepts.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a specific answer to your question, as it would seem to depend on the windowing toolkit you're using. An answer for Qt, for example, will be markedly different than someone (a masochist) writing in base Xlib.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Or with Wayland. Or direct framebuffer.

Comment: Don't expect every feature of Windows to have a Linux equivalent (and vice versa). Look at Linux with fresh eyes.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I never said I expected Linux to be like Windows. I am using Windows as a reference to communicate the concepts I'm trying to understand in Linux.

Comment: Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing intrinsic (i.e. built into the OS) like that. If you have e.g. X11, you have a similar message loop, where you receive and dispatch messages. Normally, you wouldn't see that message loop though, just as under MS Windows people rarely program on the bare win32 API. Use a so-called windowing toolkit like WxWidgets, Qt, GTK etc.

BTW: You could use an implementation of the win32 API on Linux, too, it's called WINE.